# Apps page/ Dashboard for webapps running on the same device

Tags: web-applications, raspberry-pi

I am sure I have seen something like this before:

I have a home server which is running many different webapps in containers. Pi-Hole, Portainer, Grafana, Node-Red etc. etc.

Each of these have their preferred ports, and many want to be on port 80.

I don't want to remember all these ports. Is there another containerised webapp that runs on port 80 and can link to all the other webapps running on the device.

It looks a bit like the chrome apps page but for web-services.

Answer (score 0):

[Heimdall](https://github.com/linuxserver/Heimdall) is one solution, as well as Organizr. [r/startpages](https://www.reddit.com/r/startpages/) is the place to look